# What does "Baggage: 1PC" mean on my flight ticket?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, terminology, swiss

On my e-ticket for my flight with Swiss booked through Travelup.com, I see this:

> Baggage: 1PC

Does this mean I'm only allowed hang-luggage? Or can I take hand-luggage, and check in one piece of luggage?

Comment: Looks like Baggage: 1 piece.

Comment: Yeah, but does that include hand-luggage?

Comment: Usually that would be Carry-on rather then hand luggage.

Comment: @Karlson I thought carry-on is synonymous with hand luggage (as opposed to “hold” luggage).

Comment: @Relaxed It is but more often referred to as Carry on since it makes a more clear distinction.

Comment: I have always known it as hand luggage (after looking it up, it seems “carry-on” is specifically North American) but what confused me is that your comment could be interpreted as an answer to the question rather than a terminological remark.

Comment: @relaxed That's why I specifically put it as a comment it's not an answer it's a terminological guess.

Comment: @Karlson I meant an answer to the previous comment…

Comment: For me the luggage capacity is given 7 kg minimum and maximum 15 kg
and Qty of luggage 1 piece so can i carry 2 piece of luggages

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Airlines tickets usually report the amount of allowed checked baggages. Hand luggages are usually taken for granted.

However, in this particular case, the [Swissair website](https://www.swiss.com/ch/en/prepare/baggage/free-checked-baggage) says:

> When you travel with SWISS, we will transport a certain amount of your baggage free of charge for you. The quantity and weight of this free baggage is clearly defined, and vary according to your booking class.

So I guess (if you travel in economy class) you are allowed one 23 kg checked baggage plus a 8 kg hand luggage.

Additional info on [checked baggage](https://www.swiss.com/ch/en/prepare/baggage/free-checked-baggage) and [hand baggage](https://www.swiss.com/ch/EN/prepare/baggage/hand-baggage) can be found on the same website.

Comment: carry on is ever more NOT taken for granted, as ever more airlines are charging for each and every bag, including carry on.

Comment: I took both hand-luggage and a checked suitcase and I was allowed, so your answer proved to be correct.

Comment: Good answer, There is one small issue: Swissair grounded in 2002 and is now called SWISS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swissair

Answer (score 6):

It means that you are allowed to check in one piece of luggage free of charge (as long as it isn't over the maximum allowed weight and size).

Carry-on luggage is separate.  For most airlines you are allowed two pieces of carry on.  One that will fit in the overhead compartment and another that will fit under the seat in front of you.

Answer (score -4):

the first number is for check inn baggage , airlines operating with numbers because it can be more than one . The letter P is for personal and letter C for carry on . 
Personal can be everything what is going under the sit and will fit there . Carry on is going about your head to locked shelf. Everyone think that 1PC mean one piece of something , but in real I did explained what's going on . 
for example if your ticket shows 0PC it's mean you can take only personal and carry on , because number 0 is showing zero check inn baggage , and that's apply for all airlines on the world !
Thank you

Comment: That’s actually completely incorrect. It means 1 piece of luggage when the flight operates under the “piece concept” (you are allowed a given number of pieces, each with a max weight). The alternative used to be that you were given a weight, and you could have any number of pieces as long as the total was under the given weight. Nowadays allowances can be more complex than that, it’s best to check the details on the airline’s website.

Comment: Note also that it applies only to checked-in luggage. Carry on is counted separately and often not quoted on reservations.