# What baggage allowance does 1 PC mean?

Tags: luggage, france, air-france

I am travelling on Air France and my ticket is: Baggage allowance > 1 PC.

I don`t know what that means?
Just one package on the plan or one package on the plan and one in my hand?

I am travelling for work and I have my laptop bag.

Comment: Have you attempted to [read what AirFrance writes](https://www.airfrance.us/US/en/common/guidevoyageur/pratique/bagages-soute-airfrance.htm)? If there's anything unclear, [edit] your question with more details.

Comment: 1PC = 1 Piece. 1 Checked bag.

Comment: Hand luggage or cabin baggage comes on top, usually one small case and a laptop bag, but do check your ticket or the website of the airline.

Answer (score 2):

There should be a generic answer for this as we have multiple times the same question for different airlines: [Swiss](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34652/what-does-baggage-1pc-mean-on-my-flight-ticket), [JetStar](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/86820/what-is-1pc-baggage-allowance-for-jetstar-asia-air) and [SAS](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49158/what-does-baggage-allowance-1pc-mean-on-an-sas-flight-reservation).

The meaning is the same: **One single piece of checked baggage is included in the ticket.**

What differs between airlines are the size and weight restrictions. For Air France:

- Checked luggage is limited to linear 158 cm / 62.2" inches. This means that the width, height and depth of you luggage must add up to at most 158cm or 62.2".
- The maximum weight is 23 kg / 50.7 lb in Economy or Premium Economy, or 32 kg / 70.5 lb in Business and First class.

The full text of these policies are found [here](https://www.airfrance.us/US/en/common/guidevoyageur/pratique/bagages-soute-airfrance.htm).

In addition to checked baggage, you are also allowed *one carry-on* and *one personal item*. Most laptop bags fit under the *personal item* category which are restricted to 40 x 30 x 15 cm / 16 x 12 x 6 in and specifically state *bag for a notebook computer, camera or any other electronic device*. The allowed carry-on can be up to 55 x 35 x 25 cm / 21.7 x 13.8 x 9.9 in and has a generous 12kg weight limit.